# Elastic search Group by count for particular field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elastic search index with following documents

```
    {
       "id":1
      "mainid  ": "497940311988134801282012-04-10  ",

    }

  {
       "id":2
      "mainid  ": "497940311988134801282012-04-10  ",

    }
```

I am looking to have a query similar like -example mysql table

```
id    mainid                                       
1     497940311988134801282012-04-10                

2     497940311988134801282012-04-10                
3     497940311988134801282012-04-10              
4     something different





select id ,mainid ,count(mainid) as county  from wfcharges group by mainid,id having county>1;
```

in elastic search ,as there is no count aggregate function is available in elastic .I am stuck here.This is what ,I have tried. Any suggestions or online resources.Thanks

```
GET /wfcharges/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "countfield" : {
            "count" : { "field" : "mainid" }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is going to be exactly what you need:

```js
GET /wfcharges/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "countfield": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "mainid",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's going to aggregate by `mainid` field and tell that minimum document count for this bucket has to be 2 ( more than 1):

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd want to use the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). This will group by similar terms and return a count of each term. Look at the linked url for example.

In you case, it would look like this:

```
GET /wfcharges/_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "countfield" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "mainid" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to sort out the data having doc_count >0 or ==1 ??

Comment: You can use [`order`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) to sort specified in the terms aggregation documentation.